# Intent filter matching URL

Tags: android, intentfilter

I've tried every example I've found for hours with different mix of android::path, pathPrefix etc, but can't get it to work.

How should an intent filter for my app to match this URL that looks like:"example.com/View/File/xxx" where xxx is a random file number?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" android:path="/View/File/" android:pathPattern=".*"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Then in your code:

```
String data = getIntent().getDataString();
```

Taken from [here](http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/05/19/opening-urls-with-your-application/) and the [Android Manifest Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html). I didn't have a chance to test this, if it doesn't work try messing around with the path, parthPrefix and pathPattern.

Comment: Actually there's probably a better way to get the data off of the URL rather than 'getDataString()'. You'd have to check the Intent docs though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried that combination as well, but it doesn't work. :( If I don't use path or pathPrefix at all, then it works, but takes all URLs to that site. (According to documentation, then path, pathPrefix and pathPattern needs to start with a slash) I'll keep on trying different combinations.

Comment: After some more trial and error, I found that `android:pathPattern="/View/File/.*"` works and that's the only combination that I could get to work. To me `android:pathPrefix="/View/File/.*"` should also work, but it doesn't.